# Spritz implantaion into my html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to integrate [spritz technology](http://spritzinc.com) into my [page](http://www.padhani.co.uk/webpagereader/).

Tell me please: how I can to do that?

Comment: what is "spridz technology"?

Comment: http://www.spritzinc.com/

Comment: I think you can find all the info you need here. http://www.spritzinc.com/developers/...

Comment: Thanks, i send my message to them now and waiting for answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to wait, you can use [OpenSpritz](https://github.com/Miserlou/OpenSpritz) !

[Codepen.io example](http://codepen.io/pouretrebelle/pen/lqhdH).

Edit :

(By the way, this is not my example, as wrote into the link the code belong to [pouretrebelle](http://codepen.io/pouretrebelle/))

**HTML**

```
<div class="spritz">
    <div class="spritz-word"></div>
</div>
<div class="settings">
    <div class="interaction"><a id="spritz_pause" href="#" title="Pause/Play" class="pause"></a>
    <input id="spritz_wpm" type="number" value="300" step="50" min="50" class="speed"/>
</div>
<textarea class="demo-text">
  Spritz
  Check out version 2 of this demo - it's linked in the info.
  This is a jQuery implementation of Spritz technology. Paste some text below to try it out. Change the speed and test your comprehension abilities, and click the pause button or space bar if you get a bit overwhelmed!
  Reading is inherently  time consuming because your eyes have to move from word to word and line to line. Traditional reading also consumes huge amounts of physical space on a page or screen, which limits reading effectiveness on small displays. Scrolling, pinching, and resizing a reading area doesn’t fix the problem and only frustrates people. Now, with compact text streaming from Spritz, content can be streamed one word at a time, without forcing your eyes to spend time moving around the page. Spritz makes streaming your content easy and more comfortable, especially on small displays. Our “Redicle” technology enhances readability even more by using horizontal lines and hash marks to direct your eyes to the red letter in each word, so you can focus on the content that interests you. Best of all, Spritz’s patent-pending technology can integrate into photos, maps, videos, and websites to promote more effective communication.
 </textarea>
<button id="spritz_change" class="demo-text-change">Refresh</button>
</div><a href="#" title="Change Theme" class="light"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.spritz {
  position: relative;
  width: 30rem;
  padding: 1rem 0 1.2rem;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10rem auto;
}
.spritz:before, .spritz:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  height: 0.8rem;
  width: 2px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  background-color: black;
}
.night .spritz {
  border-color: #555555;
}
.night .spritz:before, .night .spritz:after {
  background-color: #555555;
}
.spritz:before {
  top: 0;
}
.spritz:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.spritz-word {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  line-height: 3.2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.spritz-word div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.spritz-word div:first-child {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}
.spritz-word div:nth-child(2) {
  color: #e60000;
}
.night .spritz-word div:nth-child(2) {
  color: #ff4d4d;
}
.spritz-word div:last-child {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
}

.settings {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30rem;
}
.settings input, .settings textarea, .settings button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}
.night .settings input, .night .settings textarea, .night .settings button {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #1a1a1a);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #1a1a1a);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222, #1a1a1a);
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
.settings input:focus, .settings textarea:focus, .settings button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.settings .interaction {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}
.settings .pause {
  font-family: "IconicFill", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  line-height: 3.6rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  transition: color 150ms linear;
}
.settings .pause:hover {
  color: #777777;
}
.settings .pause:before {
  content: "\e049";
}
.settings .pause.paused:before {
  content: "\e047";
}
.night .settings .pause {
  color: #555555;
}
.night .settings .pause:hover {
  color: #888888;
}
.settings .speed {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 18rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.settings .speed::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.settings .speed::-webkit-inner-spin-button:before, .settings .speed::-webkit-inner-spin-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  right: 0;
}
.settings .speed::-webkit-inner-spin-button:before {
  content: "faster";
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
}
.night .settings .speed::-webkit-inner-spin-button:before {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #222222, #1a1a1a);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #222222, #1a1a1a);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #222222, #1a1a1a);
}
.settings .speed::-webkit-inner-spin-button:after {
  top: 2rem;
  content: "slower";
}
.settings .demo-text-change {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.settings .demo-text-change:active {
  padding: 1.1rem 1.5rem 0.9rem;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #eeeeee, #fafafa);
}
.night .settings .demo-text-change:active {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #222222, #1a1a1a);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #222222, #1a1a1a);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #222222, #1a1a1a);
}
.settings .demo-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  margin: 5rem 0 0;
}
.settings .demo-text::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.8rem;
}
.settings .demo-text::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #cccccc;
}
.night .settings .demo-text::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #555555;
}
.night .settings .demo-text::-webkit-resizer {
  background: #222222;
}

.light {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 3rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "IconicFill", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.light:after {
  content: "\263e";
  color: #5e606b;
}
.night .light:after {
  content: "\2600";
  color: #a6a392;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  background: #dddddd;
  color: black;
  transition: background 0.1s linear;
}
.night body {
  background: #111111;
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

body, input, textarea, button {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var wpm = $('#spritz_wpm').val();
var interval = 60000/wpm;
var paused = false;
var $space = $('.spritz-word');
var i = 1;

/* TEXT PARSING */
function words_set() {
  words = $('.demo-text').val().trim()
    .replace(/([-—])(\w)/g, '$1 $2')
    .replace(/[\r\n]/g, ' {linebreak} ')
    .replace(/\. /g, '. {period} ')
    .replace(/[ \t]{2,}/g, ' ')
    .split(' ');
  for (var j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
    words[j] = words[j].replace(/{linebreak}|{period}/g, '   ');
  }
}
/* ON EACH WORD */
function word_show(i) {
  var word = words[i];
  var stop = Math.round((word.length+1)*0.4)-1;
  $space.html(''+word.slice(0,stop)+''+word[stop]+''+word.slice(stop+1)+'');
}
/* ITERATION FUNCTION */
function word_update() {
  spritz = setInterval(function() {
    word_show(i);
    i++;
    if (i == words.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $space.html('');
        spritz_pause();
      }, interval);
      clearInterval(spritz);
    };
  }, interval);
}

/* PAUSING FUNCTIONS */
function spritz_pause() {
  clearInterval(spritz);
  paused = true;
  $('#spritz_pause').addClass('paused');
}
function spritz_play() {
  word_update();
  paused = false;
  $('#spritz_pause').removeClass('paused');
}
function spritz_flip() {
  if (paused) {
    spritz_play();
  } else {
    spritz_pause();
  }
}

/* INITIATE */
words_set();
word_show(0);
word_update();

/* CHANGE SPEED */
$('#spritz_wpm').on('input', function() {
  interval = 60000/$('#spritz_wpm').val();
  if (!paused) {
    clearInterval(spritz);
    word_update();
  }
});

/* REFRESH TEXT */
$('#spritz_change').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(spritz);
  words_set();
  i = 0;
  spritz_play();
});

/* PAUSE BUTTON AND SPACE BAR */
$('#spritz_pause').on('click', function() {
  spritz_flip();
  return false;
});
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    spritz_flip();
  }
})

/* LIGHT/DARK THEME */
$('.light').on('click', function() {
  $('html').toggleClass('night');
  return false;
});
```